# How can I add multiple new documents in a firestore collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```json
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Dry Ice',
        total: 84,
        price: 346,
    },
    {
        name: 'Chef Hat 20cm',
        total: 156,
        price: 231,
    },
   // and more data
]
```

I want to add all objects in a firestore collection as documents.

I have found [batch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) operation documentation. They show how to update the existing documents. But I want to create new documents in one request from the client side.

Comment: The documentation you linked shows you how to create documents with the set operation.  Have you tried?  A batch set operation works just like a [normal set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), except all at once.

Comment: Checkout the linked answer. `batch.set(...)` instead of `batch.update(...)` should do as Doug mentioned.